# Heat kernel upper bounds on a complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, heat-equation

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, and $p(t, x, y)$ denotes its heat kernel. I am trying to find sufficient conditions for when the following holds:
$$ p(t, x, y) \leq Ct^{-n/2}, \forall x, y, t > 0.$$

In particular, I am interested in the following question: does lower Ricci bounds imply the above heat kernel bounds?

Answer (score 1):

This was proved by S. Y. Cheng, P. Li and S. T. Yau in the paper "On the Upper Estimate of the Heat Kernel of a Complete Riemannian Manifold" when the sectional curvature is bounded between two constants. See [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2374257?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the bounds given there work for $x, y \in M$ and for $t \in (0, T]$, and the constant $C$ depends at least on $T$. Is there a hope of obtaining such bounds for a uniform $C$ independent of $T$?

Comment: In fact, I read somewhere that for nonpositively curved spaces, one can get a uniform constant $C$ that works for all $T$.

Comment: Indeed, for nonnegative Ricci-curvature the heat kernel behaves like $Ct^{-n/2}\exp(-c d(x,y)^2/t)$. See Li, Yau. On the parabolic kernel of the Schrödinger operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is Theorem 5.5.6 of the book Davies, E. B. Heat kernels and spectral theory. Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, 92.

Comment: Just a note that the same answer was given verbatim here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/279987/2926

Comment: Why not? A good reference may answer many questions.